# CS50 Week 4 Memory, when we don't reference a address to a string does it come automatically?

Tags: c, cs50

Does the char* already contain a address to the first char in this example?

When we do scanf is the 2nd parameter a real address?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    printf("s: ");
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: In this example `s` contains a "garbage" value that is pointing nowhere. So attempting to read a string theree will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: C is a very simple language, almost nothing is done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and trying to populate it with a call to `scanf("%s", s)` is undefined behavior because the pointer does not point to allocated memory.

You may initialize `s` by allocating it:

```
    s = malloc(100);
    if(NULL == s)
    {
         goto cleanup; // one of the few valid uses of goto in C
    }
     
    if(scanf("%99s", s) != 1) 
    {
        // scanf failed to populate 's'
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Hello %s\n", s);
    
cleanup:
    free(s);
    s = NULL;
```

Comment: If scanf failed, you should go to cleanup as well.

Comment: I would remove that comment about goto.

Comment: @user253751 I thought it prudent to caution OP who is clearly new at C programming about it

Comment: Since it's a political caution rather than a technical one, I wouldn't include it. There is nothing *technically* invalid about using goto however you want (as long as the language allows it). Only politically invalid.